# ASP.Net RDLC Report External Image not Showing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, image, reporting-services, rdlc

In the "Use this image" field i used a parameter. 
Generated html reveals that the src attribute is null. That's why the image is not displayed.

Please advise.

Comment: Are you saying the parameter returned a value of null? Is this linking to a hyperlink of an image, but the path is null?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Jonnus. No, the parameter does not return a null value. I tested this. In the "ToolTip" field i used this parameter. Then the alt text shows that parameter correctly. I am not using any hyperlink. I just want to set the src attribute of the image.